# How to recenter an Emacs buffer around an overlay

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to recenter an Emacs buffer so as to show as much as possible of an overlay and of its context around it.  Specifically, I want this behavior:

- If the overlay fits in the visible window, I want to show as much as line before it as lines after it;
- Otherwise, I want the beginning of the overlay to be shown.

This behavior is somewhat similar to what I see when using different regions highlighted in `ediff`.

Is there a not-so-complicated way to achieve this?  I tried to look into the `ediff` code (specifically `ediff-util.el`) but things seems very complicated to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what usage you're looking for, but this code should do what you want.
It can be called with an overlay, or if called interactively, will choose one of the overlays at the current position and do the action on it.

```
(defun make-overlay-visible (overlay)
  "given an overlay, center it on the window
(or make beginning visible if it cannot fit in the window)"
  (interactive (list (car (overlays-at (point)))))
  (when overlay
    (goto-char (overlay-start overlay))
    (recenter 0)
    (when (and (pos-visible-in-window-p (overlay-start overlay))
               (pos-visible-in-window-p (overlay-end overlay)))
      (goto-char (/ (+ (overlay-start overlay) (overlay-end overlay)) 2))
      (recenter))))
```